# Why is this paragraphs form broken with a tabledrag error?

Tags: paragraphs

I've spent many hours on this and am out of ideas. All node edit forms on our site with Paragrpahs are showing the weight/delta fields and drag and drop does not work. There is no button to toggle "Show/Hide" weights.

Other drag-and-drop sections, like block management, are okay, it seems only paragraphs are displaying this issue.

It's as if the Paragraph fields are stuck in "Show Weight" mode but there is no option to disable it.

Drupal 10.2 | The latest version of Paragraphs setup to (Stable) Widget on the form. We have the same setup on other sites and it does not have this issue so there must be a setting or something off on this site but I am unable to figure what is causing this.

[image]

NOTE: Console shows what appears to be a related JS error but still don't know why:

[image]

Screenshot after clicking EDIT ALL:

[image]

Comment: Change the admin theme temporarily to a core one - same problem? Your table looks broken, the admin theme you're using might be incompatible with tabledrag

Comment: Hi Clive, I've changed the admin them to Gin, Claro and Bootstrap, no change.

Comment: What provides the "Edit all" button functionality? Disable that temporarily and I'd wager the problem will disappear

Comment: I've also uninstalled all toolbars, including Gin Toolbar. Made sure no JS was getting inserted from modules like Injector, etc.

Comment: Edit All comes from Paragraphs, we have other sites with same themes and setup (as far as I can tell) and it renders correctly (Edit All is still there but the weights are hidden and the toggle shows and works)

Comment: The best approach to debug might be comparing the table HTML from the broken site to a version of HTML from a working site. That should show you what’s different and you can’t start hunting what causes it

Comment: Thank you Clive, I spent many hours yesterday comparing the sites and the only difference I see is that the working site is loading an additional tabledrag.js from the Claro theme which the broken site is not doing. Working site has both core tabledrag.js and also themes/claro/js/tabledrag.js - these two files are named the same both are different code. I have no idea why working site loads claro's tabledrag also but that is the only difference I could find.